# How to send push x hours later with Node.js / Heroku / Wit.ai ChatBot on Messenger

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing ChatBots on Messenger with Node.js and Heroku + Wit.ai.
**My problem :
 I would like to know if it's possible to send a push XX hours after the last interaction and how to do it.**
I already have Facebook ID stored in a database. I don't know how to automatically contact again the user 1 hour after the last message send to the bot. If you know how to do that, I will appreciate any help.
 Thank You

Comment: The question is a bit broad. But have you thought of wrapping the respond method via setTimeout(function(){  respond_to_user()  }, 3000);

Comment: I'll just tack on that there's [an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) for time-based tasks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already hosting this, your best bet is to have a background task that checks some kind of queue constantly, and fires off any events in that queue that are an hour old. You could use something like [heroku scheduler](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/02/10/defining-node-dot-js-task-for-heroku-scheduler/) as well.

What have you tired?

Comment: Thank you for this ! I didn't know Heroku's Scheduler ! It's seems to be great and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again